# What are those black spots on my ambient occlusion bake?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

I wanted to bake an ambient occlusion map to my model, but on the baked texture, there are two big black dots on the sides (on each side one).

I don't have much experience with baking and textures altogether. I tried recalculating normals and removing doubles, but nothing helped. The dots are more or less circular, placed symmetrically and they don't copy the faces of the model (they have a  different shape). Here's a picture:

[image]

The part with those dots is selected. The model is made with mirror modifier and should be symmetrical (now the modifier is applied).

Comment: I checked the older versions (I keep everything as a safety copy) and this spot isn't there in the begining and appears during rigging and gets bigger. I can't say what edits there were.

Comment: It could it be a hidden, but renderable, object that is secretly occluding a part of your mesh during baking. Is the object alone on the layer?

Comment: I go with Carlo's suggestion. There are at least three hidden objects according to the outliner window.

Comment: Lol, I was going to suggest the exact same thing. The other thing that's at least worth thinking about is if the armature could have deformed the mesh at all. It looks a lot like an intersection...

Comment: That was it (it's a model of a whole creature and this part is only a helmet. I hid it so that the problem would be more visible). Thanks a lot.